# CraftCMS admin login page error "Account Suspended"

Tags: login, migration, user-interface

Our website was created a couple years ago and our web designer is no longer with us. We have had access to the admin  portion of our site and this is how we keep it up to date.

This week when we went to sign in to the admin site an error that comes up "Account suspended". I have no idea how to 'fix' this.

The actual site  is working just fine.

I called Bluehost and they said everything is good on their end. I have tried CraftCMS but all they tell me is that the original person that set it up would need to do it.

I have not worked with CraftCMS before on the back-end, so I am a little lost...
Is there a way to regain admin access on the front-end? If I am not the original creator how can I access the back-end ?
If not is there a way to migrate the site and where do you recommend we migrate it to (WordPress?)

Thank you !!!

Lisa

Comment: You say that the old developer is "no longer with us". Assuming this isn't a metaphor and they are actually still alive, it sounds like that person may have suspended your account. You may want to reach out to them directly.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this is an all too common occurrence. The good news is this is fixable.

If your account was suspended, you need to unsuspend it. Typically you'd do this on the backend of the site.  If don't have any users who have the appropriate user permissions, there is a way to do it.

Are you comfortable "breaking" into your own website?

Basically you (or someone at BlueHost) would need to run some MySQL code to update the database:

```
update users set suspended = 0 where users.email = 'your@email.com';
```

Replace 'your@email.com' with the email address associated with the account in question.

If your database was setup with a "prefix", commonly `craft_`, it'd look like this instead:

```
update craft_users set suspended = 0 where craft_users.email = 'your@email.com';
```

If this all greek to you, which it might be, BlueHost might be able to help you. However, I don't how much help shared hosting providers like Bluehost are able to troubleshoot.

I would recommend having a [Craft partner](https://craftcms.com/partners) look at your website as well. Since your web person is now missing in action, your Craft CMS installation itself may need additional maintenance and updates.

When we build websites for clients we also help them with on-going hosting and maintenance. Unfortunately too many agencies or freelancers build and run and don't support the sites they create and clients pay the price.